# Read/edit values starting from a Telerik RadGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have this situation:

[image: A Telerik RadGrid]

... a normal RadGrid with data. And, if I clic on a row, I want to obtain this:

[image: Another Telerik RadGrid]

... a list of label-textbox pair (please pay attention: these list of data are obtained from the row, but are not part of it).

With the first RadGrid it's all okay.
Therefore, I have used a simple HTML Table for the list of pair (in the second image). This list being generated code-behind, from database.

**The problem is the update of the TextBoxs**: if I edit these textboxes and do clic on the Update Botton, starts the *myRadGrid_UpdateCommand* method. But I can't find a way to manage these textboxes (they don't appear in *myRadGrid.Controls* or else).

So I have tried to use another RadGrid inside the first RadGrid, but with no luck... Maybe I have to use another different Telerik control?

Someone know how I can do this?

This is part of my implementation:

```
    protected void myRadGrid_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    this.myRadGrid.DataSource = this.dtListaDettagli;
    this.dtListaDettagli.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { this.dtListaDettagli.Columns["key"] };
}


protected void myRadGrid_ItemCreated(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is GridEditFormItem && e.Item.IsInEditMode)
    {
        GridEditFormItem item = (GridEditFormItem)e.Item;
        UserControl userControl = (UserControl)e.Item.FindControl(GridEditFormItem.EditFormUserControlID);
        var listOfDetails = this.Session["listOfDetails"];
        //...
        var dtoTrav = (List<Detail_Type_N>) listOfDetails;
        PopolaUC(dtoTrav, userControl, e.Item.ItemIndex);
    }
}


private void PopolaUC<T>(List<T> data, UserControl uc, int index) where T : FlussiBaseDto
{
    // ...
    RadPane radPane = uc.FindControl("RadPane1") as RadPane;
    var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(Detail_Type_N));
    // ...
    var dettaglioSelected = (from x in data
                             where x.IdFlusso == idFlussoSelected && x.ProgDettaglio == progDettaglioSelected
                             select x).FirstOrDefault();

    HtmlTable htmlTable = new HtmlTable();
    htmlTable.ID = "DettaglioSinistro";
    var tRow = new HtmlTableRow();

    int i = 0;
    foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
    {
        i++;
        if (i > 3) // organizza la sottotabella in 2 colonne
        {
            tRow = new HtmlTableRow();
            i = 1;
        }

        // Set label:
        HtmlTableCell tLabel = new HtmlTableCell();
        var stringInNormalCase = Regex.Replace(prop.Name, "(\\B[A-Z])", " $1");
        tLabel.InnerText = stringInNormalCase;
        tRow.Cells.Add(tLabel);

        // Set TextBox:
        HtmlTableCell tCell = new HtmlTableCell();
        // ...
        TextBox box = new TextBox();
        box.Text = Convert.ToString(prop.GetValue(detailSelected));
        box.ID = string.Format("my_{0}", prop.Name);
        tCell.Controls.Add(box);


        tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
        htmlTable.Rows.Add(tRow);
    }
    radPane.Controls.Add(htmlTable);
}


protected void myRadGrid_UpdateCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    GridEditableItem editedItem = e.Item as GridEditableItem;
    UserControl userControl = (UserControl)e.Item.FindControl(GridEditFormItem.EditFormUserControlID);

    //Prepare new row to add it in the DataSource
    DataRow[] changedRows = this.dtListaDettagli.Select("key = " + editedItem.OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues[editedItem.ItemIndex]["key"]);

    // ... and then?

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        changedRows[0].CancelEdit();

        Label lblError = new Label();
        lblError.Text = string.Format("Errore nell'aggiornamento movimento. Errore: {0} ", ex.Message);
        lblError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        RadGridIpa.Controls.Add(lblError);

        e.Canceled = true;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: See this article maybe it will help you http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Gridview-inside-Gridview-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You cannot generate TextBoxes and Labels dynamically.

Instead, you want to use [Edit Form](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/data-editing/form-template-update/defaultcs.aspx).

For example,

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" ...>
   <MasterTableView>
      ...
      <EditFormSettings>
          Place those textboxes and lables here.
      </EditFormSettings>
   </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: Why I can't? I have already done this... My problem is the updating

Comment: Well. You can add any server control dynamically, but retrieve them back on post back is the problem. Those dynamically added control are not in the control tree, so when the page posts back, they will become null.

Comment: I understand. It's really strange.. there is a way to bypass this problem? I really have the necessity of create labels-texboxes dynamically..

Comment: It is the downside of ASP.Net Web Form. Work around is to place all controls inside **EditFormSettings**, and show and hide inside **ItemCreated** event based on your business logic.